# Converting SQL GROUP_CONCAT with concatenation to Peewee code

Tags: python, peewee

I'm trying to convert an SQL query that uses the GROUP_CONCAT function with concatenation to Peewee code. However, I'm having trouble with the concatenation part.

Here's the original SQL code that I want to convert:
`SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(' ' || t2.value1 || '|' || t2.value2) AS rates`

It works with sqLite terminal but not sure how to convert it to peewee.

So far, I tried to use `+ operator` and `fn.concat()` like below, but it didnt worked as expected.

`fn.GROUP_CONCAT(' ' + ModelName.t2.quantity + '|' + ModelName.t2.rate).alias('rates')`

```
fn.GROUP_CONCAT(
            fn.concat(' ', ModelName.t2.value1, '|', ModelName.t2.value2)
        ).alias('rates')
```

When I use fn.concat(), my `query.objects()` return error for `len()` like below
`TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peewee overrides "+" for string-type columns to perform concat, but I'm guessing your field-types must be numeric. In that case, you can do the following:

```
class Amt(db.Model):
    key = TextField()
    val1 = IntegerField()
    val2 = IntegerField()

db.create_tables([Amt])

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(1, i + 3):
        Amt.create(key='k%s' % i, val1=j, val2=j * 2)

exp = Value(' ').concat(Amt.val1).concat('|').concat(Amt.val2)
q = (Amt.select(fn.GROUP_CONCAT(exp).alias('rates')).group_by(Amt.key))
for row in q:
    print(row.rates)
```

Outputs:

```
 1|2, 2|4
 1|2, 2|4, 3|6
 1|2, 2|4, 3|6, 4|8
 1|2, 2|4, 3|6, 4|8, 5|10
 1|2, 2|4, 3|6, 4|8, 5|10, 6|12
 1|2, 2|4, 3|6, 4|8, 5|10, 6|12, 7|14
 1|2, 2|4, 3|6, 4|8, 5|10, 6|12, 7|14, 8|16
 1|2, 2|4, 3|6, 4|8, 5|10, 6|12, 7|14, 8|16, 9|18
 1|2, 2|4, 3|6, 4|8, 5|10, 6|12, 7|14, 8|16, 9|18, 10|20
 1|2, 2|4, 3|6, 4|8, 5|10, 6|12, 7|14, 8|16, 9|18, 10|20, 11|22
```